# How to get a second level field from json file using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm work with json gem in ruby. Im trying to print second level field such as [address/city/born_in].My ruby code is

```
json = File.read('person.json')
person = JSON.parse(json)
pp person
puts person["address"]["city"]["born_in"]
```

My json file as follows..,

{
   "FirstName":"John",
   "lastName":"Smith",
   "age":25,
   "address":[
      {
         "streetAddress":"21 2nd Street",
         "state":"NY",
         "postalCode":"10021"
      },
      {
         "city":{
            "born_in":"New York",
            "living_in":"Mumbai"
         }
      }
   ]
}

It shows the following error..,

```
parsingjson.rb:15:in `[]': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
        from parsingjson.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `address` field is an array. You should use indexes to refer to its elements.

```
puts person["address"][0]["streetaddress"]
puts person["address"][1]["city"]["born_in"]
```

Answer (score 0):

the result of person['address'] is Array,
you can use this

```
puts person['address'][1]['city']['born_in']
```