# Rails how to display hash from JSON request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash

I'm trying to display the inner levels of the hash from my JSON request.

This is the return from JSON request:

```
{
    "results": [
    {
    "utc_offset": -25200000,
    "venue": {
      "zip": "94305",
      "country": "us",
      "localized_country_name": "USA",
      "city": "Stanford",
      "address_1": "750 Escondido Road",
      "name": "Ray's - Graduate Community Center",
      "lon": -122.158386,
      "id": 5612552,
      "state": "CA",
      "lat": 37.423393,
      "repinned": false
    },
    "status": "upcoming"
    },
    {
    "utc_offset": -25200000,
    "venue": {
      "zip": "94306",
      "country": "us",
      "localized_country_name": "USA",
      "city": "Palo Alto",
      "address_1": "25 Churchill Ave",
      "name": "Palo Alto High School",
      "lon": -122.154121,
      "id": 1566333,
      "state": "CA",
      "lat": 37.433186,
      "repinned": false
    },
    "status": "upcoming"
    },
    {
    "utc_offset": -25200000,
    "venue": {
      "zip": "94306",
      "country": "us",
      "localized_country_name": "USA",
      "city": "Palo Alto",
      "address_1": "25 Churchill Ave",
      "name": "Palo Alto High School",
      "lon": -122.154121,
      "id": 1566333,
      "state": "CA",
      "lat": 37.433186,
      "repinned": false
    },
    "status": "upcoming"
    }
    ]
    }
}
```

I've referred to: [How to use JSON data returned by API call in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666913/how-to-use-json-data-returned-by-api-call-in-rails-4), [How to get a second level field from json file using ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106717/how-to-get-a-second-level-field-from-json-file-using-ruby), [Why do I get "no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19549098/why-do-i-get-no-implicit-conversion-of-string-into-integer-typeerror),  [How to access JSON in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245039/how-to-access-json-in-rails)

Which helped me get to this point, I can display the inner levels of the hash if I specify the array index using `@result = @api_response["results"][0]["venue"]["name"]` which returns `"Ray's - Graduate Community Center"`. This is what I am trying to display, but I wanted to display the name for all the venue on the list and not just the name at index [0]. But I'm not sure how to iterate through the index.

I can also display the hashed results by using `@result = @api_response["results"]` and iterate through using:

```
<% @result.each do |i| %>
  <%= i["venue"] %>
<% end %>
```

Which returns:

```
{"zip"=>"94305", "country"=>"us", "localized_country_name"=>"USA", "city"=>"Stanford", "address_1"=>"750 Escondido Road", "name"=>"Ray's - Graduate Community Center", "lon"=>-122.158386, "id"=>5612552, "state"=>"CA", "lat"=>37.423393, "repinned"=>false} 
{"zip"=>"94305", "country"=>"us", "localized_country_name"=>"USA", "city"=>"Stanford", "address_1"=>"750 Escondido Road", "name"=>"Ray's - Graduate Community Center", "lon"=>-122.158386, "id"=>5612552, "state"=>"CA", "lat"=>37.423393, "repinned"=>false} 
{"zip"=>"94306", "country"=>"us", "localized_country_name"=>"USA", "city"=>"Palo Alto", "address_1"=>"25 Churchill Ave", "name"=>"Palo Alto High School", "lon"=>-122.154121, "id"=>1566333, "state"=>"CA", "lat"=>37.433186, "repinned"=>false} 
{"zip"=>"94306", "country"=>"us", "localized_country_name"=>"USA", "city"=>"Palo Alto", "address_1"=>"25 Churchill Ave", "name"=>"Palo Alto High School", "lon"=>-122.154121, "id"=>1566333, "state"=>"CA", "lat"=>37.433186, "repinned"=>false} 

{"zip"=>"94306", "country"=>"us", "localized_country_name"=>"USA", "city"=>"Palo Alto", "address_1"=>"25 Churchill Ave", "name"=>"Palo Alto High School", "lon"=>-122.154121, "id"=>1566333, "state"=>"CA", "lat"=>37.433186, "repinned"=>false} 
{"zip"=>"94306", "country"=>"us", "localized_country_name"=>"USA", "city"=>"Palo Alto", "address_1"=>"25 Churchill Ave", "name"=>"Palo Alto High School", "lon"=>-122.154121, "id"=>1566333, "state"=>"CA", "lat"=>37.433186, "repinned"=>false}
```

But when I try using this:

```
<% @result.each do |i| %>
  <%= i["venue"]["name"] %> <br />
<% end %>
```

I get a `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass` error, it does not let me access the "name" inside of "venue" which I am trying to display.

Am I on the right track? Is there a better way to display the inner levels of the hash? Any feedback would help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are on the right track; it's just that there's a result in there that is either nil or that doesn't have a venue within it.

How you approach the problem depends on what you want to do those situations.

You could filter the results to exclude results without a venue. It would be more efficient to do this as part of your query but you could just do:

```
@result.select { |r| r.present? && r.has_key?('venue') }.each do |i|
```

Alternatively you could output "no venue" or somesuch if the venue is missing. I tend to use [`fetch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-fetch) in situations like this. You can try to fetch the value from the hash but return a default if the key isn't in the hash. So, in your case, you could do:

```
<%= i.fetch('venue', {}).fetch('name', 'No venue') %>
```

This looks for the venue hash in the result but returns an empty hash if it isn't there. The second `fetch` then tries to retrieve the name from that hash and again returns `'No venue'` if it couldn't find it.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, they both work really well. With the `fetch`, I was able to see which entries had `'No venue'`. One question, is it possible to add the `'No venue'` message to this `@result.select { |r| r.present? && r.has_key?('venue') }.each do |i|` ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that every object in the `results` array has a `venue` field?

Before trying to access the `venue` field, make sure to see if the object actually exists. In your controller, add this

```
@result = @api_response["results"].reject {|obj| obj.nil?}
```

This will remove any object in the array which is `nil`.

What if the object exists but the field `venue` doesn't?

```
<% @result.each do |i| %>
  <%= i.has_key? "venue" ? i["venue"]["name"] : 'Location unspecified' %> <br />
<% end %>
```

If this looks messy, you could also move it to a helper method like

```
def venue_name(obj)
  obj.has_key? "venue" ? obj["venue"]["name"] : 'Location unspecified'
end
```

And then make use of it in the view.

```
 <% @result.each do |i| %>
  <%= venue_name(i) %> <br/>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried `<% @result.each do |i| %>
  <%= i.has_key? "venue" ? i["venue"]["name"] : 'Location unspecified' %> <br />
<% end %> ` and still got `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` error. But I do understand now that the `venue` might be missing for some of the `results` hence the error.

Comment: @tshckr Thats strange. Are you able to display `i["venue"]`?

Comment: Yup, that seems to work, but I get newline randomly which I think that's where the `venue` field may be `nil`? I edited my question above to add more lines to what was returned from `i["venue"]`

Comment: @tshckr I have updated my answer. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I tried it but received the same `nil` error. These answers provided from Shadwell: `@result.select { |r| r.present? && r.has_key?('venue') }.each do |i|` and `<%= i.fetch('venue', {}).fetch('name', 'No venue') %>` did work. But I am not trying to ignore the results with no `venue` I want to display them as well except with a "TBD". Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @tshckr, thanks for trying my solution. I think you misinterpreted my answer. My code only rejects objects which are nil and not objects which don't have a `venue` field. Remember you saw newlines when you tried to display objects in the array? Thats because one of the objects was `nil`. This is necessary because `obj.has_key? "venue"` can only be done  if `obj` is not `nil`. Thanks again!